# Use SFPro fonts in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I downloaded the new SFPro fonts from this url https://developer.apple.com/fonts/. And I can see that it is properly installed in Font Book. But when I try to use it as System font inside my app's UILabel, it gives me the SFUI fonts instead. (I print the system font with the code below and it prints '.SFUIText')

```
print(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15).fontName)
```

How can I use new SFPro fonts instead of SFUI? My Xcode version is 8.2.1 and the software is El Capitan version 10.11.16.

Comment: I want to use it in the app , I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moritz

Answer (score 0):

I am successful in using it by following steps:

1) Add font files to your project

2) In your info.plist press on the plus button. Type Fonts provided by application. Add your font files names for example (SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf)

3) Make sure the font file has your project as a targeted membership by clicking on the file and then ticking on checkmark under target membership section